# Identifying AEM Content Fragments related to a particular field value updated in a csv

Tags: csv, fragment, adobe, aem

When a Content Fragment is updated by drawing values from a linked csv file, is there a way to identify only those CFs that are related to the particular field value, updated in the csv file?

Suppose we only update the income for Year1 in a sample csv file (row: Income, column: Year1) and this csv may be linked to a number of CFs but I only want to find the CFs containing the particular field value updated, that is income for year1.

I initially thought this would trigger an event for the CF updated as it would have for any other update that we do to CFs directly but in this case an event trigger is not happening possibly because it's drawing values from an updated csv file.

What would be a possible solution to this problem?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow supri! i do curious is this question really related to [tag:cfml] which refers to adobe's cold fusion (an entirely different product to [tag:aem]).

Comment: Hi @BagusTesa, Thanks for the comment. Yes you're right, this is not related to cfml, sorry it was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way. In general, it depends on how you upload the csv file in AEM.

You can implement an event listener to monitor changes in the csv file. If it is updated, you can take the path from the event data, parse the contents and update the CFs.

If you are updating the csv file via Sling Post Servlet, then you can implement `org.apache.sling.servlets.post.PostOperation` and put the logic in it.